# Propagate custom event to parent swf from element inside child swf

Tags: actionscript-3, events

I have two swf file, A.swf and B.swf, each with its Document Class: B.swf is loaded in a MovieClip of A.swf. When loaded, B.swf creates an instance of CSDragger (it is a library object with its class extending MovieClip) and sets an ID property of this instance to a certain value. When this dragger is dropped by the user upon a MovieClip it sends a custom event containing the value of ID too. **The custom event regularly reaches B.swf but never reaches A.swf.** Aside from refactoring the CSDragger class (eg moving its handleDrop method in the B.swf document class), is there any way for the event to reach A.swf? I know I can intercept it and dispatch another event, but I was looking for a different solution (if any).

The following is contained in the body of A.swf document class constructor:

```
var ldr = new Loader(); 
ldr.load(new URLRequest("B.swf")); 
menuLoader_mc.addChild(ldr);
```

---

This is the custom event class: the CSDragger class fires an ITEM_DATA event that reaches the document class of B.swf (but not the document class of A.swf). Of course there are listeners inside B.swf and A.swf.

```
package events { 
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher; 
    import flash.events.Event; 

    public class ItemEvent extends Event { 
        public static const ITEM_DATA:String = "ItemData"; 
        public var data:*; 

        public function ItemEvent(type:String, data:*) 
        { 
            this.data = data; 
            super(type, true); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Presumably the custom event has bubbling set to true?  If so, do you catch it anywhere in B.swf and call `stopPropagation()`?

Comment: Also, could you post the code you use to load B into A?

Comment: Oh, I don't call stopPropagation();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that there is a direct line of ancestry on the display tree between the object that dispatches the event and the root of B.swf (I see you edit, there is).

You may be having an ApplicationDomain issue, so try to load in B.swf using the context from A.swf:

```
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
var ldr = new Loader(); 
ldr.load(new URLRequest("B.swf"),context); 
menuLoader_mc.addChild(ldr);
```

Comment: I get two errors: access to undefined currentDomain property AND addChild wrong number of arguments.

Comment: (it seems by *helping* you edit my question I lost about 15 points)   :-)

Comment: Sorry, my bad, trying to rush! I'll edit... (and let me try to help with those rep points)

Comment: No, it doesn't work: as before, it reaches B.swf main, but never A.swf.

Comment: Shane, maybe I found: I pretended to listen to the event in A.swf AND B.swf, but maybe I can listen only in one place. I don't know if this is true, but if I comment the addEventListener inside B.swf, the event fires in A.swf.

Comment: No, I think something else is wrong.  I just built a quick test an the event fires fine from both at the same time.  Where do you add the listener in A.swf, to menuLoader?

Comment: Oh: there was no context issue (I tested this too). Only I did not imagine I could not listen to the same event from two different places.

Comment: Moved discussion to chat...http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1613/discussion-between-lotus-and-shanethehat